# Define URL in GA code to track that web address

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is there a way in JS to define the url for Google Analytics you are trying to track?

So far my code is as follows:

```
(function(window, document){

  var gaData = {
    Name: "Test",
    shoppingBagView: 'Shopping View',
    checkClick: 'Check Bar Clicked',
  };

  ga('send', 'event', gaData.Name, "pageview", gaData.shoppingBagView);

  $('.button1').on('click', function(){
    ga('send', 'event', gaData.Name, "click", gaData.checkClick);
  });

})(window, document);
```

Is there a way I can define the url I want to track?

Comment: Do you want to see this URL as an event parameter, a custom dimension, or the page path itself?

Comment: So I would like to define the url as a variable and add that to the tracking

Answer (score 0):

You should update the page field on the tracker.
You can find how to, and more details, here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#modifying_page_urls